# The command for start neovim or vim in the linux terminal don't work

Tags: vim, neovim

First of all, I am using a translator because I speak Spanish, so I apologize for the lack of meaning in the sentences.

A few hours ago I reinstalled Ubuntu on my computer which is an Acer Aspire A515-55, I have a dual boot with Windows 10 which I don't think has much to do with it.

But the problem is that when I use the "nvim" or "vim" command, this line appears: 11;rgb:1818/1818/1818 or 11;rgb:3030/0a0a/2424.

I tried to find someone else who had this problem but I haven't found anyone else.

I already tried to reinstall neovim and vim two times and in both cases the same thing happens, at no time have I been able to open the programs since I installed Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Also, I tried to open the text editors from the shortcut in the favorites bar but it doesn't work either, it just shows a window of something I think, it's a terminal and it closes. This is so with both programs, both Vim and Neovim.

[Using the terminal with the command "nvim"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygTQt.png)

[I tried to star Vim or NeoVim form there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCijk.png)

Sorry for my ignorance and thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: "*I speak Spanish*" https://es.stackoverflow.com